# How to change QTableView border color?

Tags: qt, user-interface, styles, qt4, qt5

I have a QTableView, I can open a lot kinds of files, but when I open one specific kind i want to know that by changing the border color of the QTableView

How can I change the color of the QTableView ?
border of all the QTableView not borders of the cells

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use styleSheet. Set this styleSheet when you load your specific file.

```
ui->tableView->setStyleSheet("QTableView{border : 1px solid red}");
```

Comment: thanks, used the setStyleSheet function with the string border : 1px solid red
worked as expected.